# Proof that $\zeta'(-2n)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n+1)$.

Tags: riemann-zeta

How would one prove the following statement which I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Derivatives), and/or does anyone know of a reference with a proof?

$$\zeta'(-2n)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n+1).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof follows from the [reflection formula of $\zeta(s)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) given by $$\zeta(s)=2^{s} \pi^{s-1} \sin \frac{\pi s}{2} \Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s).$$

We want to differentiate with respect to $s$ at $s=-2n$. This would seem to be difficult, but note that $\sin\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\Big|_{s=-2n}=-\sin(\pi n)=0$ for integer $n$. Since the derivatives of the rest of the equation turns out to be finite at $s=-2n$, it follows that the only nonzero part of $\zeta'(-2n)$ comes from differentiating the sine function. Thus we have as claimed

\begin{align}
\zeta'(-2n)
&=\left[2^{s} \pi^{s-1} \Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(\sin\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\right]_{s=-2n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)^{-2n} \Gamma(1+2n)\zeta(1+2n)\cos(-\pi n)\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n+1).
\end{align}

Comment: It should be noted that deriving the reflection formula requires some labor; see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Functional_Equation_for_Riemann_Zeta_Function) for one method of proof.